# how to get adjusted bounce rate in Omniture sitecatalyst

Tags: bounce, adobe-analytics

adjusted bounce is defined as 'bounces excluding the single page visits that have finished some interactions on the page'; for instance, single page visits that stay longer than 15 seconds, or trigger an ajax event; I want these visits to be excluded from bounce rate calculation

I know in GA it can be adjusted quite easily by customizing the GATC, but I haven't found anything about Sitecatalyst, does anyone have any idea?

thanks!

Comment: A visit that consists of a single server call. For example, a single page visit is a bounce if a visitor does not interact with the page in a way that sends data to Adobe, such as clicking a link or a video start. If more than a single hit is received in a visit, a Bounce is not counted.

Answer (score 1):

In SiteCatalyst, a "bounce" is considered a single image request (no other calls, not even [custom links](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/index.html#Link_Tracking)). Based on what you're looking for, I'd anticipate this is the segment you're looking for:

```
Include all visits where time spent on page is greater than 15 seconds
Exclude all visits where path length is greater than 1
```

Keep in mind this cannot include single page visits that did not send a custom link image request, nor can it track visits where more than one s.t() call was fired. It only includes visits where a single s.t() was fired, and at least one custom link.